# Cannot invoke event inside another Event handler (Dependency Service)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have the following issue. In the code below I have an event which I can invoke from the method GetSmSInbox() but inside the OnReceive() it is not working because its null. The subscription is done In the main project. So the question is why is it Null and how can I invoke it from the OnReceive(). Is it because the OnReceive is an overriden method and it then puts the execution on a separate tread ?

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SmsBroadcastRceiver))]
namespace SmsServiceApp.Droid
{
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" })]
public class SmsBroadcastRceiver : BroadcastReceiver , ISmsReader
{

    SmsBroadcastRceiver()
    {

    }
    public event EventHandler<OnSmsReceivedEventArgs> OnSmsReceive;




    public void GetSmsInbox()
    {
        //Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Tess Dependency", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        OnSmsReceive?.Invoke(this, new OnSmsReceivedEventArgs("Test"));

    }


    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        var msgs = Telephony.Sms.Intents.GetMessagesFromIntent(intent);

        foreach (var msg in msgs)
        {

               OnSmsReceive?.Invoke(this, new OnSmsReceivedEventArgs(msg.DisplayMessageBody));
            // Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, msg.DisplayMessageBody, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

The Interface Implementation

```
public interface ISmsReader
{

     void GetSmsInbox();
     event EventHandler<OnSmsReceivedEventArgs> OnSmsReceive;

}
```

The subscription

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pullRequestButton.Clicked +=  delegate {

            Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<ISmsReader>().GetSmsInbox();
        };



        Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<ISmsReader>().OnSmsReceive += OnSmsReceived;

    }

    private void OnSmsReceived(object sender, OnSmsReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        editorSms.Text = e.MSG;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we talk this issue about invoking it from the OnReceive().
If you want to read the SMS, you add following permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" />
```

And Read the SMS is a [dangerous permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview). You should grant it at the runtime

Next, if we want to achieve broadcastrecevier in the dependence service, we should create a broadcastrecevier, then register it in the dependence service

Here is my code about `broadcastrecevier`. I use `MessagingCenter` send the message from Android to PCL

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" })]
public class SmsBroadcastRceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{

    public SmsBroadcastRceiver()
    {

    }



    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        var msgs = Telephony.Sms.Intents.GetMessagesFromIntent(intent);

        List<string> msgList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var msg in msgs)
        {
            msgList.Add(msg.DisplayMessageBody);

        }

        MessagingCenter.Send<List<string>>(msgList, "MyMessage");
    }
}
```

Here is `MySmsReader`

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MySmsReader))]
namespace ScanDemo.Droid
{
 public class MySmsReader : ISmsReader
{
    public void GetSmsInbox()
    {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.AddAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");


        SmsBroadcastRceiver receiver = new SmsBroadcastRceiver();
        Application.Context.RegisterReceiver(receiver, filter);
       // RegisterReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is code about Interface

```
 public interface ISmsReader
{

    void GetSmsInbox();

}
```

Here is foreground code.

```
 <Button Text="open broadcase" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
 <Label x:Name="editorSms"/>
```

Background code.

```
   public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<List<string>>(this, "MyMessage", (expense) =>
        {
            List<string> mylist= expense as List<string>;
            string allText= "";
            foreach (string item in mylist)
            {
                allText += item+"  ";
            }
            editorSms.Text = allText;
        });



    }



    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<ISmsReader>().GetSmsInbox();
    }
```

Here is a running GIF about my demo.
[image]

Comment: Here is my demo:https://github.com/851265601/BroadcastReceSMS ,I didnot achieve it runtime persmission, you should grant permssion manually.

Comment: With the MessagingCenter is working .Still don't understand why with event was not but since is working that was should be good.